# RealmQuery : do I need to reassign the result of a query operator to the query object every time?

Tags: java, android, realm

Frequently I see code snippets like this:

```
public RealmResults<MyObject> getMyObjects(List<Integer> ids) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class);
        for (int i=0; i< ids.size(); i++) {
            query = query.equalTo("id", ids.get(i));
            if (i != ids.size() -1) {
                query = query.or();
            }
        }
        return query.findAll();
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) realm.close();
    }
}
```

Is it really necessary to reassign the output of a query operator to the RealmQuery object? Will this other snippet achieve the same result? (hint: i have removed `query =` before the calls to `.equalTo()` and `.or()`)

```
public RealmResults<MyObject> getMyObjects(List<Integer> ids) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class);
        for (int i=0; i< ids.size(); i++) {
            query.equalTo("id", ids.get(i));
            if (i != ids.size() -1) {
                query.or();
            }
        }
        return query.findAll();
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) realm.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query essentially functions like a builder, so in reality, the returned builder has its state set with the given condition. This means that the assignment is optional.

This is why queries like the structure of the one below work:

```
query.equalTo(...).equalTo(...).beginGroup()....endGroup().findAll()
```

The returned parameter is `this` and not a new RealmQuery.

Comment: Thanks I was adding a comment to the previous answer you downvoted but it has disappeared.

I looked at the implementation of `equalTo()` and it ends with `return this`: I thought it must then modify the state of the same RealmQuery object it was invoked onto (via side effects). If this is true is it ok to entail that reassignment is not needed therefore?

Comment: You are correct, the reassignment is not needed. It's just there for clarity I think.

Comment: I had this question once and read through the source, so it's true :)